# Java - Simplest way to get characters that come after substring inside string

Tags: java, string

How can I get a list of characters in a string that come after a substring? Is there a built-in String method for doing this?

```
List<String> characters = new ArrayList<>();
String string = "Grid X: 32";
// How can I get the characters that come after "Grid X: "?
```

I know you could do this with a loop, but is there another way that may be simpler?

Comment: You could try a split on the word "Grid X:" and then select from the resulted array the first element[position 0] or your could split by ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the characters after the ": "

```
String string = "Grid X: 32"
int indexOFColon = string.indexOf(":");
String endNumber = string.subString(indexOFColon + 2);
```

So you get the index of the colon, which is 6 in this case, and then grab the substring starting 2 after that, which is where your number starts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. Use a regular expression (regex):

   ```
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Grid X: (\\d+)");
   if (m.matches(string))
   {
       int gridX = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
       doSomethingWith(gridX);
   }
   ```
2. Use the substring method of the string:

   ```
   int gridX = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(string.indexOf(':')+1).trim());
   doSomethingWith(gridX);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used for getting list of chacters :-

```
String gridString = "Grid X: 32";

String newString = gridString.subSubString(gridString.indexOf(gridString ) +  gridString    .length );
char[] charArray = newString.toCharArray();
Set nodup = new HashSet(); 
for(char cLoop : charArray){
nodup.add(cLoop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to get this done.  The simplest is probably just substring.  But it is fraught with danger if the string doesn't actually start with "Grid X: "...

```
String thirtyTwo = string.substring( s.indexOf("Grid X: ") + "Grid X: ".length() );
```

Regex is pretty good at this too.

Comment: I gave you one because I do not see any explanation of down voter