# how to extract a substring from a given string in java

Tags: java, string, split

I want to extract substring of a given string. 
the example string is `rta=0.037ms;3000.000;5000.000;0; pl=10%;80;100;; rtmax=0.125ms;;;; rtmin=0.012ms;`

I want to get only 0.037ms after "rta=" and percent after pl=. I tried to splite the above string by space and then by semicolon. did not work.

Comment: write a regex statement or use string.spit() and split at the spaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Simplest way to get characters that come after substring inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346818/java-simplest-way-to-get-characters-that-come-after-substring-inside-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String s = "rta=0.037ms;3000.000;5000.000;0; pl=10%;80;100;; rtmax=0.125ms;;;; rtmin=0.012ms;";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("rta=(.*?);.*pl=(.*?);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. i almost wrote the same regex but missed the semicolons. it helped thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "rta=0.037ms;3000.000;5000.000;0; pl=10%;80;100;; rtmax=0.125ms;;;; rtmin=0.012ms;";
String[] parts = str.split(";");
String part1 = parts[0]; // rta=0.037ms
String part2 = parts[4]; // pl=10%
...

System.out.println(part1.substring(4)); // 0.037ms
System.out.println(part2.substring(4)); // 10%
```

Comment: probably you meant `String string = ...` not `str`

Comment: @Carlos, yes.. typo mistaken :)

Comment: The second sout should be, System.out.println(part2.substring(4));

Comment: @karna, yes.. I see one space on there :)

Comment: Thanks again for this answer too. this is also the right answer. thanks again.